# Hacking PHP code with SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have some code like this which is open to SQL injection. We got hacked and now we fixed it. I just want to know what the inputs (username and password) must be in order to hack this code. I mean even if you input

```
username = something' OR 'x'='x
```

Then you can retrieve the password of the first user in the table regardless of the username. However, inside the `if` we check whether this password is correct. I am assuming the password was very easy (as easy as `123456`) and the hacker made a brute-force from a dictionary. However I am wondering if there is another way to hack this code using some injection other than brute-forcing the password.

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$result=runQuery("SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE username='".$username."''");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row['password']==$password){
    -- do sth... create a cookie etc..
}
else{
    --go to another page...
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't believe you read about sql injection.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: To protect against sql injection, you need to use `PDO`, or `mysqli`. You aren't even escaping your input in your example. As Mike said, I don't really believe that you read anything about sql injection in the first place.

Comment: Username: [`Bobby'; DROP TABLE tbl_users; --`](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Sammitch I think you are missing your space at the end of your injection ;)

Comment: What was the effect of hacking?

Comment: What's the url, we can't test it otherwise.... ;)

Comment: @JohnConde I had never heard of that, thank you. OP, you should read about paramaterized queries. If you're working on a website that involves a log in system, you should be familiar with and know how to fix/avoid the OWASP top ten security risks. [Here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Table_of_Contents)

Number 1 is SQL injection.

Comment: The hacker did not drop a table or anything. The table was there, the password was not updated. This user account is used for adding a short comment to a wall. There were comments of the hacker on the wall.. and the tbl_users was untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variable binding in PDO library.

Answer (score 2):

If hacker pass value:

`$username = "' OR * OR '"`

then query will be:

`SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE username='' OR * OR '';` - this will be select any user.

But hacker can:

`$username = "'; DELETE * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = * OR '";`

`SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE username = ''; DELETE * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = * OR '';`

Or can made `UPDATE` to change any password.

Safety? `mysql_real_escape_string` or `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15}$/", $username)`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But doesnt he have to know the table names in order to manipulate them? tbl_users is not known... 
 
$username = "'; DELETE * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = * OR '";

Comment: Of course, but if `error_reporting` is on, this can leak. Also, hacker can try random query combinations

Answer (score -1):

Using boolean blind or time blind injection hacker can retrieve all the database structure.

Example:

```
username = 'admin' and if(1=1, sleep(10), 5222) #
```

This query gonna take 10 second to return and confirm that your condition is `true` or `false`. Using the information_schema and SQL condition test you can retrieve all databases information.