# How to show warning alert after form submit using ajax and php?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a scenario in user management section where before creating a user, I need to make sure the username already exists or not. On the successful insertion success message is shown after form submit but I can not figure out how to show the warning alert if I try to create a new user with existing username. In order to check if username already exists or not I have checked the row in user table, the code I tried is given below...

```
$sql="select * from user where username='$username'";
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$row_no=mysqli_num_rows($result);
/*if($row_no<1){*/
if($_POST["user_id"] != '')  
  {  
       $query = "  
       UPDATE user   
       SET fullname='$fullname',   
       user_role='$user_role',   
       username='$username',   
       password = '$password',   
       branch_id = '$branch'   
       WHERE user_id='".$_POST["user_id"]."'";  
       $message = 'Data Updated'; 
       if($_SESSION['user_id']==$_POST["user_id"]){
       $_SESSION['username']=$username; 
       $_SESSION['user_role']=$user_role;
       $_SESSION['fullname']=$fullname; 

       }

  } else{

$query = "
INSERT INTO user(fullname, user_role, username, password, branch_id,registered_date)  
 VALUES('$fullname', '$user_role', '$username', '$password', '$branch','$registered_date')


";

  }
if(mysqli_query($connection, $query))
{

 $select_query = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user_id DESC";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $select_query);
 $output .= '

                 <table style="background-color:#FFF;" id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                      <thead>  
                           <tr>  
                                <th>User ID</th>  
                                <th>Fullname</th>  
                                <th>User Role</th>  
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Password</th>  
                                <th>Branch</th> 
                                 <th>Registered Date</th>
                                 <th>Action</th>  


                           </tr>  
                      </thead> 

 ';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {

  $output .='

   <tr>  
                                <td>'.$row["user_id"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["fullname"].' </td>
                                <td>'.$row["user_role"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
                                 <td>'.$row["password"].'</td> 
                                 <td>'.$row["branch_id"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["registered_date"].'</td>  
                         <td>

 <Button id="'.$row["user_id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs edit_data">
 <i class="fa fa-edit "></i></Button> &nbsp' ;
if($_SESSION['user_id']!=$row["user_id"]) {
 $output .='<a id="'.$row["user_id"].'"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs 
 delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>';
 }



 $output .= '</td></tr>';
 }
 $output .= '
 </table>

 <div id="success-alert" class="alert alert-success fade in m-b-15">
                            <strong>Success!</strong>
                            Data Updated.
  <span class="close" data-
  dismiss="alert">×</span>
                        </div>


<script>$("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 
500).slideUp(500, function(){
$("#success-alert").slideUp(600); });</script>

                        ';
}


    echo $output;


}
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835803/hacking-php-code-with-sql-injection). Storing passwords as plain-text is not done. Please have a look at [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to properly store your passwords

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a submit u can use...

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Rest of your code...
});
```

And to show error messages...

You can make an array in your handler and adding an error in the array
After all the validations do one more validation on your array filled with the errors.
When there are errors you can display a div and fill those with your arrays.